# Does -dataWithContentsOfURL: of NSData work in a background thread?

Tags: iphone, nsdata

Does -dataWithContentsOfURL: of NSData work in a background thread?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

In order to get data from URL asynchronously you should use the `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` approach.

You will have to implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: This post shows an example of how to use `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` on a background thread to achieve the same result: http://londonwebdev.com/2011/01/13/retrieving-remote-images-on-background-threads-on-the-iphone/

Comment: Of course! Anything may be done in a background thread, But it wasn't the question. In addition, I would do the same with NSOperationQueue rather than as it is implemented in the post that you have mentioned...

Comment: @user8472, Read the question and the answer once again... The method `dataWithContentsOfURL` is NOT executed in background by itself. Obviously, you can execute anything (almost) in the background thread. You have many possibilities - not only the one I have suggested (which is the parallel solution to `dataWithContentsOfURL`). You could also implement it by `performSelectorInBackground...`, `NSOperation` + `NSOperationQueue`, blocks (as you have mentioned) and few other ways... The bottom line - there is no conflict in my answer.

Comment: It seems the original question is ambiguous - it could be interpreted to read either way.  Actually I found my way to this page wondering if it was possible to run it on a background thread (I've now confirmed that it is possible).  I've never edited a question - is this the sort of thing we could edit it for - to clarify the ambiguity?  This could help future people who come to this question.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using dataWithContentsOfURL in a background thread fine.

```
-(void)loaddata {
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"some url"];
    if (data == nil) {
        DLog(@"Could not load data from url: %@", url);
        return;
    }
}
```

Call something like this from main thread.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loaddata) withObject:nil];
```

If you want to perform updates to ui at end of loaddata, be sure to call a function on main thread.

Answer (score 7):

No. You can use NSURLSession instead, though.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSString *imageURL = @"Direct link to your download";

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]] completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
    });
}]; 
[getImageTask resume];
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it blocks the current thread.

You need to use `NSURLConnection` in order to have asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 3):

Also you may use -dataWithContentsOfURL + NSOperation + NSOperationQueue

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this has changed a bit over the years.  But, these days,

```
NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error) {
}];
```

will give you an async network call.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will block the thread and you will load the contents of file into the RAM. You can download  content directly into file without temporary NSData to avoid huge RAM usage. Something like this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215458/2937913