# Downloading large files

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently developing a application which has to be able to show offline videos which need  to be downloaded first.

The problem was that these videos can be bigger that the memory that I can allocate to my application. So parts that are downloaded have to be saved immediately instead of saved in a NSData object. I'm hearing conflicting stories on whether or not RESTKit should work, and ASIHTTPRequest seems to be deprecated.

I will follow the suggestion from this thread as it seems to be the best option.

[NSURLConnection download large file (>40MB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215095/nsurlconnection-download-large-file-40mb)

Comment: Ok thanks for giving the notification, I'll remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `NSURLConnection` to download the video file and write the data directly to a file (`NSFileHandle`).

One advantage of using this method is that the `NSURLConnection` `didReceiveData` delegate method is continuously called as data is received, so you can update a progress bar.

Comment: This seems like the most viable option... I'll try it later today. (don't worry if it works ill accept you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out AFNetworking for network managing. I am not sure if they have video downloading, but the framework works great for images and other types of downloads that I have down before.

Answer (score 0):

Without explaining all the hasle with dealing with HTTP responses by chunks and streams I would recommend using [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation). It supports resuming downloads and has callbacks for showing download progress. I love it and use it in most of my projects.

P.S. It uses [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which is a great framework for making all kinds of HTTP requests.

Comment: Do you happen to have a cocoapod file for this... I can't get it to work and reconfiguring the workspace is such a hassle.