# What are the limits of NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm making an app and sometimes i will require to download zip files of more than 200MB of size... is there a limit for NSURLConnection other than the timeout? and also for NKAssetDownload since my app uses newsstand features. Apple recommends using a single connection for a single issue, and there for recommends using zip files. The file size is already optimized. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use up the user's limited monthly data plan like that.

Comment: @SLaks It might be over wifi.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6215095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` can work with gigabytes of data. There is no limit tied to `NSURLConnection`. Disk space and keeping the app running during the download are the real limits. And obviously don't keep all of the data in memory. Write to a file as you get the data.