# A bit help for using queuing and Grand Central Dispatch on iOS

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsjsonserialization, queuing

This is my problem, I'm building an iOS with some JSON returs from my server, here, no problems, all works fine.

The problem is that when I run the program, it take a long long time to parse the result into a `NSMutableArray`: this is the log

```
2013-01-10 12:03:48.627 project[5917:907] <- time begin parser
2013-01-10 12:03:48.755 project[5917:907] <- time finish parser
2013-01-10 12:03:48.756 project[5917:907] <- time begin implement arrays
2013-01-10 12:03:58.522 project[5917:907] <- time finish implement array
```

As you can see, implementing the arrays is **really** long.

I know that I have to use queueing and grand central dispatch to make my UI responsive, but I don't know how to, could you please help me to do that ?

This is my `viewDidLoad` Method

```objc
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if debug
        NSLog(@"<- time begin parser");
    endif


    NSString *URLStr = @"http://myJsonFile.json";

    NSDictionary *myDictwithReturn = [TOCJSONParser awesomeParserWithStringOfYourJSONFile:URLStr]; //really cool parser, i can put it on gitHub if you want
    NSArray *speakersArray = [myDictwithReturn objectForKey:@"speakers"];

    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"<- time finish parser");
    NSLog(@"<- time begin implement arrays");

    for (NSDictionary *myDict in speakersArray) {

        _nextSpeaker = [[TOCSpk alloc]init];
        [_nextSpeaker setName:[myDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [_nextSpeaker setBusiness:[myDict objectForKey:@"business"]];
        [_nextSpeaker setDesc:[myDict objectForKey:@"desc"]];
        [_nextSpeaker setTwitter:[NSURL URLWithString:[myDict objectForKey:@"twitter"]]];
        [_nextSpeaker setPicture:[_nextSpeaker retrieveImageFromServer:[myDict objectForKey:@"picture"]]];
        [myArray addObject:_nextSpeaker];
    }

    NSLog(@"<- time finish implement array"); 
}
```

Comment: It seems there's an error in your code. Shouldn't the loop be:  `for (NSDictionary * myDict in speakersArray) `?

Comment: edited, thx, but it's not the pb here, just edited the code to be more explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the slowness comes from calling `retrieveImageFromServer`, which lets me think that you are accessing the network. If that access is synchronous, as it seems from the fact that you are assigning the image in the same statement, than this is bound to be slow.

You should review your code and make it run on a separate thread or use asynchronous network access.

EDIT:

After your comment about using, `dataWithContentsOfURL`, my above hypothesis is confirmed.
You can read [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078765/does-datawithcontentsofurl-of-nsdata-work-in-a-background-thread) about a way to download images asynchronously, or you might use any of various networking frameworks available out there.

Possibly, the easiest path forward is using [SDWebImage](http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), which is a class that offers async download for images, so you don´t have to bother yourself with thread management or `NSURLConnection`:

> Just #import the UIImageView+WebCache.h header, and call the `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` method from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` `UITableViewDataSource` method. Everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching management.

Comment: In fact this method doesn't call the server at all, it just instanciate an UIImage from a URL string parsed in JSON file

Comment: and where does the image data come from? have you already downloaded it? is it bundled within the app?

Comment: i have JSON attribute in the http://myjsonfile.json entitled "pictureURL" : "http://myurl.com/img.png" and then the method is something like 
(UIImage *)myMethodname:(NSString *)picturePath {
 UIImage *myimage [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picturePath]]];
return myImage;
}

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` will access the network synchronously.

Comment: Ok, could you tell me how to do this async and to put it in my array then, thx

Comment: just edited my answer; have a look at `SDWebImage`, I think it will make things easier.

Comment: In fact i still have a pb, i import the .xcodeproj file to frameworks, i'll linked ImageIO and set the -ObjC flag but i've got
`SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h file not found` :/

Comment: either you add the path to `SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h` to your target build settings (header search path) or you add the `.h` file itself to your project (in this case, the compiler should find it on its own).

Comment: I change my method, i copy all .m .h file in a group, and as i see MKAnnotationView, i also add MapKit.framework and it's work fine :-)