# How to retrieve array of images from array of url swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm trying to retrieve images from array of url..

I have this function that do the same as I won't but it doesn't work so I tried to use URLSession but didn't know how exactly to make it >>

```
func downloadImages(imageUrls: [String], completion: @escaping (_ images: [UIImage?]) -> Void) {
        
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
    var downloadCounter = 0
    
    for link in imageUrls {
        let url = NSURL(string: link)
        let  downloadQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "imageDowmloadQueue")
        
        downloadQueue.sync {
            downloadCounter += 1
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
            
            if data != nil {
                //image data ready and need to be converted to UIImage
                imageArray.append(UIImage(data: data! as Data)!)
                
                if downloadCounter == imageArray.count {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(imageArray)
                        
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("couldnt download image")
                completion(imageArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function I work on :

```
public func imagesFromURL(urlString: [String],completion: @escaping (_ images: [UIImage?]) -> Void) {
        
        var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
        var downloadCounter = 0
        let  downloadQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "imageDowmloadQueue")

        for link in urlString {
            downloadQueue.sync {
            downloadCounter += 1
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: link)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error ) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "No Error")
                return
            }
            
            if data != nil {
                imageArray.append(UIImage(data: data! as Data)!)
                if downloadCounter == imageArray.count {
                    completion(imageArray)

                    }
                } else {
                            print("couldnt download image")
                            completion(imageArray)
                           }
                
            } dataTask.resume()
                }
            }
}
```

i want to call the function in the collection cell and get the display the first image only from each artwork array..

```
        //download the first image only to display it:
        if artwork.ImgLink != nil && artwork.ImgLink.count > 0 {
            
            downloadImages(imageUrls: [artwork.ImgLink.first!]) { (images) in
                self.artworkImage.image = images.first as? UIImage
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you intend to use only the first available `UIImage` from an array of urls, you do not design a function trying to download all of them. Instead, try to download from the first url, return the downloaded `UIImage` if it succeeds, or continue with the second url if it fails, repeat until you get an `UIImage`.
2. Creating a `DispatchQueue` in a local function looks dangerous to me. A more common practice is to maintain a queue somewhere else and pass it to the function as a parameter, or reuse one of the predefined global queues using `DispatchQueue.global(qos:)` if you don't have a specific reason.
3. Be careful with `sync`. `sync` blocks the calling thread until your block finishes in the queue. Generally you use `async`.
4. Use a `Int` counter to control when to finish multiple async tasks (when to call the completion block) works but can be improved by using `DispatchGroup`, which handles multiple async tasks in a simple and clear way.

Here's two functions. Both work. `firstImage(inURLs:completion:)` only return the first `UIImage` that it downloads successfully. `images(forURLs:completion:)` tries to download and return them all.

```swift
func firstImage(inURLs urls: [String], completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        for urlString in urls {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(image)
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}

// Use it.
firstImage(inURLs: artwork.ImgLink) { image in
    self.artworkImage.image = image
}
```

```swift
func images(forURLs urls: [String], completion: @escaping ([UIImage?]) -> Void) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var images: [UIImage?] = .init(repeating: nil, count: urls.count)
    
    for (index, urlString) in urls.enumerated() {
        group.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            var image: UIImage?
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                    image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
            images[index] = image
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(images)
    }
}

// Use it.
images(forURLs: artwork.ImgLink) { images in
    self.artworkImage.image = images.first(where: { $0 != nil }) ?? nil
}
```

Comment: Don't use Data(contentsOf: url) to load data from a non local resource/ Not even from a background thread.

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you elaborate on this? Apple suggested not to use Data(contentsOf:) for a remote url because it blocks the current thread: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init. What are the reasons for preventing using it from a background thread?

Comment: You are using a synchronous initialiser for the wrong purpose. Use the URLSession methods which are the proper methods for asynchronous requests. related https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078783/2303865

Comment: I think you should take some time and read those articles as well [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system), [Downloading Files from Websites](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_from_websites),  [Pausing and Resuming Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/pausing_and_resuming_downloads), [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background)

Comment: Still not answering the specific question "What are the reasons for preventing using it **from a background thread**?". URLSession is indeed for asynchronous requests (data or file), but **without additional efforts**, it seems have no significant difference from using Data(contentOf:) in a background queue.They both fetch the image once into memory without any optimization, i.e. decoding, cache, invalidation. However, optimization is a much deeper question which beyonds this post and there's libraries addressing it.

Comment: Nope downloadTask doesn't load the data to memory. Btw dataTask can not be run in the background and/or be resumed. If Apple did want you to use Data(contentsOf: URL) for async requests they would only say there for you to call it on a background thread instead of telling you to use URLSession.